# Create a site collection in root path with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, spsite

I am trying to create a new site collection with powershell in the root path http://mysite/search/

```
    $siteName = "Search";
    $webAppUrl = "http://sharepoint";
    $siteUrl = "$webAppUrl/$siteUrl";

    New-SPSite -Url $siteUrl -OwnerAlias $ownerAlias -SecondaryOwnerAlias $secondaryOwnerAlias -ContentDatabase $databaseName -Template $template -Name $siteName;
```

I get the error below:

> New-SPSite : A site collection could not be created as the provided
>   managed path does not exist.

Comment: 1. Is that really the full path in the webAppUrl variable? 2. Why do you wanna create a search site in the mysites webapplication?

Comment: @user19952 it is not the mysite web application. I want to create it in the root of the deafult web application. http://sharepoint/<here>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to create an site collection, you need to create an explicit managed path for "/search". In central administration, under the manage web applications screen, highlight the web application, then select managed path.

Create an explicit managed path called "/search" and try your powershell script again.